# Java program to check course id numbers entered, such as IT1000 .I cannot get it to print out each characters specific errors, correctly

Tags: java, output

I am trying to write a Java program that will check course id numbers entered,  such as IT1000.  I must verify that each of the first two characters are respectively lower or upper case i then t.  Then that each digit is a digit.  I must return results saying the either the code entered was correct or incorrect with a breakdown of each error.  Such as character two was not an T or t, and Character 3 was not a digit.  The code I have so far is below.  I cannot seem to get it to print specific errors per character, correctly.  I appreciate your help.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class U4A1ValidateCourseCode {
    private static Scanner input;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter course code to validate i.e. IT2249: ");
        //assign value to input
        String code = input.nextLine();

        // split into first letter and second letter from course code
        char firstLetter = code.charAt(0);
        char secondLetter = code.charAt(1);
        char firstNumber = code.charAt(2);
        char secondNumber = code.charAt(3);
        char thirdNumber = code.charAt(4);
        char fourthNumber = code.charAt(5);
        boolean firstLetterCheck = true;
        boolean secondLetterCheck = true;
        boolean firstNumberCheck = true;
        boolean secondNumberCheck = true;
        boolean thirdNumberCheck = true;
        boolean fourthNumberCheck = true;
        // split digit letters from the source code
                String digitCharacter = code.substring(2, code.length());

                // Check for the numeric value
                boolean numeric = true;
                try {
                    int num = Integer.parseInt(digitCharacter);
                } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                    numeric = false;
                }


        if  (code.length() != 6) {
            System.out.println("You must enter exactly six characters i.e. IT2249.  You entered " + code);
            System.exit(1);
        }
        // check for the first letter
        if (!Character.isAlphabetic(firstLetter)) {
            firstLetterCheck = false;
        }
        // check for the second letter
        if (!Character.isAlphabetic(secondLetter)) {
            secondLetterCheck = false;
        }
        //check for 1st digit
         if (!Character.isDigit(firstNumber)) {
            firstNumberCheck = false;
        }   
        //check for 2nd digit
        if (!Character.isDigit(secondNumber)) {
            secondNumberCheck = false;
        }
        //check for 2nd digit
        if (!Character.isDigit(thirdNumber)) {
            thirdNumberCheck = false;
        }
        //check for 2nd digit
         if (!Character.isDigit(fourthNumber)) {
            fourthNumberCheck = false;
        }


        else if (firstLetterCheck && secondLetterCheck && firstNumberCheck && secondNumberCheck
                && thirdNumberCheck && fourthNumberCheck) {
            System.out.println("Course Code "  + code + " is valid.");
        } 
        else {
            System.out.println("Course Code " + code + " is not Valid :");
            System.out.println("First Letter is not i or I: "  );
            System.out.println("Second Letter is not t or T: " );
            System.out.println("Third character is not a digit: " );
            System.out.println("Fourth character is not a digit: ");
            System.out.println("Fifth character is not a digit: " );
            System.out.println("Sixth character is not a digit: " );
        }

    }

}
```

sample response :

```
Enter course code to validate i.e. IT2249: itit00
Course Code itit00 is not Valid :
First Letter is not i or I: 
Second Letter is not t or T: 
Third character is not a digit: 
Fourth character is not a digit: 
Fifth character is not a digit: 
Sixth character is not a digit:
```

Comment: You know already how to use an `if`. Just think about the condition when a particular error message has to be written.

Comment: Try using a `debugger` to step through the code.Your final print statements seem like they should also be printing the proper variables. That might help you debug the issue.

Comment: you better off with with mighty `regular expression`

Comment: Hi guys, I am super new at this.  I have tried all I can think of but it just is not coming toghether.  What I need is for my entry itit00 to come back saying that the course code is incorrect, and the third character is not a digit, and the fourth character is not a digit.  It is returning that all all the characters are wrong.  Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your main logic problem is the `else` never executes if any of the previous checks for problems are true.

Simplify:

- Delete all your `char` and `boolean` variables
- Delete the conversion to number code block - it's useless because other checks will catch it
- Delete checks for `isAlphabetic()` - they are useless because later more specific checks cover that
- **Print the error reason as part of the check**

Change your code to look like this:

```
String code = input.nextLine().toLowerCase();

// keep your length check

if (code.charAt(0) != 'i' && code.charAt(0) != 'I') {
    System.out.println("First Letter is not i or I: "  + code.charAt(0));
}

// similar for char 1

if (!Character.isDigit(code.charAt(2))) {
    System.out.println("Third character is not a digit: " + code.charAt(2) );
}

// similar for chars 3-5
```

If you need an overall `boolean` result (not stated, but reasonable that you eventually want one), try this:

```
boolean OK = code.matches("[iI][tT]\\d{4}"); // uses regex to check the whole input in one operation
```

Or if you just want to print an "OK" message:

```
if (code.matches("[iI][tT]\\d{4}")) {
    System.out.println("Course Code " + code + " is valid.");
}
```

Comment: Thank you -those were beautiful suggestions.  One question:  I do need it to print out an overall result.  How do I add this boolean statement? I tried these options.  They return that it Course Code is valid no matter if it is or isn't.                                                                                            else if (code.matches("[iI][tT]\\d{4}")); {
 System.out.println("Course Code "  + code + " is valid.");
}

Comment: A Bohemian, I see that, I tried to type it in just like that and it did not work. Elipse give a error saying the value of the local variable ok is not used. It did run the code but:My result is Enter course code to validate i.e. IT2249: iti112
Course Code iti112 is valid.
Third character is not a digit: i

Comment: @Alina please read my answer *carefully*. **Either** create the boolean variable (and use it somewhere), **or** use the `if`. There is no way that `code.matches("[iI][tT]\\d{4}")` will be true for `"iti112"` - your problem is elsewhere.

Comment: You are correct!  I needed to use both in the proper way.  Done and it works.  Thanks so much! I learned a lot. Bohemian==HERO

Answer (score 0):

I think the following is what you want.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Ideone {
    private static Scanner input;

    public static void print(String message){
        System.out.println(message);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter course code to validate i.e. IT2249: ");
        //assign value to input
        String code = input.nextLine();

        // split into first letter and second letter from course code
        boolean fail = false;
        char firstLetter = code.charAt(0);
        char secondLetter = code.charAt(1);

        if(code.length() != 6){
            print("Course code is incorrect, it should have 6 characters. Like - iT1234.");
            fail = true;
        }
        else if(firstLetter != 'i' && firstLetter != 'I'){
            //print("First letter should be `i` or `I`.");
            fail = true;
        }
        else if(secondLetter != 't' && secondLetter != 'T'){
            //print("Second letter should be `t` or `T`.");
            fail = true;
        }
        else{
            String lastFour = code.substring(2);
            try{
                int courseCde = Integer.parseInt(lastFour);
            }
            catch(NumberFormatException e){
                fail = true;
                //print("All last four characters of course should be numbers.");
            }
        }
        if(!fail)
    print("Right course code!");
        else if(code.length() == 6){
            for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++){
                checkForChar(code.charAt(i), i+1);
            }
            print("Wrong input format!");
        }

    }

    public static void checkForChar(char ch, int pos){
        if(pos == 1 && ch != 'i' && ch != 'I')print("First letter should `i` or `I` instead of " + ch);
        else if(pos == 1){print(pos + " is correct choice.");return;}
        if(pos == 2 && ch != 't' && ch != 'T')print("Second letter should `t` or `T` instead of " + ch);
        else if(pos == 2){print(pos + " is correct choice.");return;}
        if(pos > 2){
            try{
                int num = Integer.parseInt(""+ch);
                print(pos + " is correct choice.");
            }
            catch(NumberFormatException e){
                    print(pos + " should be digit instead of " + ch);
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Link to code - [Ideone link](https://ideone.com/ZDmnjp)

Answer (score 0):

Use String.[charAt(index)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#charAt(int)) and compare it with a character literal enclosed by a pair of single quotes. E.g.

```
String s = "XX1234";
boolean isFirstLetterI = s.charAt(0) == 'I' || s.charAt(0) == 'i';
```

To make comparison of characters easier, convert the string to all lowercase characters using [toLowerCase()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toLowerCase());

```
s = s.toLowerCase();
boolean isSecondLetterT = s.charAt(1) == 't';
```